# What's wrong in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function valButton(btn) {
    var cnt = -1;
    for (var i=btn.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
        if (btn[i].checked) {cnt = i; i = -1;}
    }
    if (cnt > -1) return btn[cnt].value;
    else return null;
}
function valForm(form) {
    var btn = valButton(form.value);
    if (btn == null) alert('Kein Radio-Button ausgewählt');

    if(btn != null) document.setfav.submit();


}
</script>
```

my form:

```
<form name="setfav" action="account/favsave" method="POST">
.
<input type="radio" name="group_shops" value="2">Supermarkt</input>
.
<input class="button" type="button" value="Add" onclick="valForm(setfav); ">
</form>
```

using symfony 1.4

no action at all, when i do onclick. thanks for help!

Comment: how do i get an error in javascript?

Comment: E.g. using Firebug: http://getfirebug.com/javascript/

Comment: Is this an online test or what? What's wrong with this code? lmao

Comment: @Pekka He probably doesn't have an idea. The code doesn't work so he just assumed something is wrong.

Comment: thanks for the comments. i am new in javascript. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Comment: `valForm(document.forms['setfav'])` ... also this line is an error...`var btn = valButton(form.value);` get a field's value, not the forms value. if you are referring to the button... then use valForm(this) instead

Answer (score 3):

`setfav` won't be defined; I think you probably meant `document.setfav`.

Comment: @craphunter: Does that mean it worked or does that mean it didn't work? :D

Comment: @craphunter: The error is probably `valButton(form.value)`, then. What are you *trying* to get with `form.value`?

Comment: @craphunter Use Chrome's Javascript console, it will show you the error, the line number where the error occurred.

Comment: @craphunter If you want to get the button's value instead of the form, use `valForm(this)`

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get it. I just want to check if the value is a Number.

Comment: @craphunter: Pass `form.group_shops` to `valButton`, not `form.value`.

Comment: @craphunter Also your html tag is incorrect... `</input>` there is no closing tag for `input`.